# JAVA exact version required Rundeck Self Contained Launcher Install "rundeck-3.3.10-20210301.war"

Tags: rundeck

We are planning to use Rundeck Self Contained Launcher Install version "rundeck-3.3.9-20210201.war" . What is the Exact JAVA version which supports this launcher.

below is the command it will install the above said launcher, Just want to know the exact JRE or JAVA version which supports below command.

java -jar rundeck-3.3.10-20210301.war

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK 8 or OpenJDK 11. Check that information [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/system-requirements.html#java).